# G-orbits for groups

Tags: group-theory

What does it mean to find a decomposition of a set say S into G-orbits? Where G is our group. I am familiar with the usual orbit definition but I haven't come across G-orbit notation anywhere? Can someone please explain. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably in this case you have an action of the group $G$ on the set $S$, see sections "[Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Definition)" and "[Orbits and stabilizers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers)"
of the respective Wiki article.